# Increment counter if object already in the basket - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I don't want to add a product to the basket again if its already in, just increment a counter. How do I keep track of each objects `count`?

```
this.state = {

    description: '',
    commaSalesPrice: '',

    items: []
};
```

The items are coming from my backend and have a `uid` and a bunch of other fields. I only care about `description`, `commaSalesPrice` and `count` at the moment. What would be the best practice to keep track of each item?

I tried adding a `count` variable to the state but `this.state.items[someIndex].count` doesn't exist, since my backend object don't have a count variable, which would be stupid to add.

```
addProductToBasket = (description, commaSalesPrice) => {

    if(description === '' || commaSalesPrice === '') {
      alert("Bad input!")
      return;
    }

    var newArray = this.state.items.slice();

    var itemToBeAdded = {
      description : description,
      commaSalesPrice : commaSalesPrice,
      uid: Math.random()*3
    }; 

    const alreadyInBasket = this.incrementItemCount(itemToBeAdded);

    if (alreadyInBasket) {
      this.setState({count:count++});
    } else {
      newArray.push(itemToBeAdded);
      this.setState( {items:newArray} )
    }
  }

  incrementItemCount(itemToBeAdded) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.items[i] !== undefined) {
        if (this.state.item[i].description === itemToBeAdded.description) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


<Table className='table'>
   <TableHead>
       <TableRow>
           <TableCell>Description</TableCell>
           <TableCell>Price</TableCell>
           <TableCell>Amount</TableCell>
       </TableRow>
   </TableHead>
   <TableBody>
      {this.state.items.map(item => {
          return (
            <TableRow key = {item.uid}>
               <TableCell>{item.description}</TableCell>
               <TableCell numeric>€{item.commaSalesPrice/100}</TableCell>
               <TableCell numeric>{item.count}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            );
      })}
   </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Don't get confused by `uid: Math.random()*3` - I only do that so I don't get warnings since I do work with some non-backend products.

Should I just make a new Component and map all the fields there and add a count variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it - you are using item's `description` as a key. In this case you can use this:

```
addProductToBasket = (description, commaSalesPrice) => {
    if(description === '' || commaSalesPrice === '') {
        alert("Bad input!")
        return;
    }

    var items = this.state.items.slice();
    var item = items.find(el => el.description === description);
    if (!item) {
        item = { description, commaSalesPrice, uid: Date.now() + Math.random(), count: 0 };
        items.push(item);
    }

    item.count += 1;
    this.setState(() => ({ items }));
}
```

I'm using Array.prototype.find, you can read about it here - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

If you need to support older browsers, than you can add polyfill or write helper:

```
getItemByDescription(description) {
    var items = this.state.items;
    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (items[i].description === description) {
            return items[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And replace:

```
var item = this.getItemByDescription(description);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping! Where should I put count? I just want to increment a value that's bound to a product and display it next to it in the table without displaying the same product again in case it's there.

Here's what state looks like atm.

`this.state = {

    description: '',
    commaSalesPrice: 0,
    count: 0, ? here ?

    items: [],`

Comment: In my version of code, it will be placed inside 'items'.

Comment: You will be able to use it later like:

`var items = this.state.items.map(item => (<div key={item.uid}>{item.description} - {item.count}</div>);`

Comment: That's so cool! I didn't even know that works. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: Any idea how to make the UI not show `count` in the table? It shows up as NaN and 0 in the count column while the array's size is 1.

Comment: The easiest way will be 
`{item.count ? item.count : ""}`

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to separate the basket object from the data itself that come from the server.

maybe add basket property to the state with

```
this.setState({
    basket: {
     itemId: 0,
     itemId2: 0
    }
})
```

and increment those values.

Comment: `commaSalesPrice` and `description` are only there to be able to add new items. Currently just for testing. You mean adding `items: [ {count: 0}]` ? I actually tried that and I get a syntax error at this point `this.setState({items.count: items.count++});`

Comment: Maybe like this? `this.state = { basketItems[ { Product: Product, counter: 0 } ] } `